# Angular - Show dropdown after write @ on input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, rxjs

My Objective is to **show a dropdown menu** when i start to write **@** on the input field.

My Component

```
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith('@'),
        map(val => val.length >= 1 ? this.filter(val): [])
      );
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
    console.log(this.options)
  }
```

This is what i have done, but its not working.

HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #inputField type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Well you didn't really connected the input in your template with the input in your code... Look for ViewChild Decorator in angular docs... Then you select the input by its #marker and should be able to access it... Or you use the (change) event to register a handler Methode like I described below... I will add an example when I am home

Comment: Thanks @Florian, i apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscription is working great.

You just forget to escape the `@` in **filter** function since you don't have an `@` in your **option List**.

Try this :

```
filter(val: string): string[] {
  return this.options.filter(option =>
    option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase().replace('@', '')) === 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just register to the change event on your input - for example:

```
(change)='handlerMethode($event)'
```

Check input for index of `@` and if you find do what you want.